# Is there any way to restrain the ADT data so that only the valid data could be constructed?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, algebraic-data-types, type-theory

When I want to define **Integer**, I tried this

```
data Int = Pos Nat | Neg Nat
data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat
```

but after written down the above codes, I found that both `Pos Zero` and `Neg Zero` are possible to be constructed, which is not expected.

And  when I want to define **Rational**, the same problem occurs again

```
data Rational = Rational Int Int
```

I’m expecting that for any `Rational n m`, it should satisfy `m > 0 && gcd n m == 1`

But I have known no way to make sure that my ADT data satisfies these properties. So when I’m writing some functions which process it as input, I have to consider these Illegal situations. **I hope that there is some way I can define the properties once when the ADT is defined, instead of checking the properties each time when I’m using it**.

Comment: This question is very broad. In the first case you could simply interpret `Neg n` as denoting `-(n+1)`. In the second, if you want `Rational 1 2 == Rational 2 4` to hold judgmentally, you need [quotient types](http://jozefg.bitbucket.org/posts/2014-10-17-quotients.html) which don't feature in Haskell

Answer (score 4):

For integers this is very easy:

```
data Nat = Zero | Positive Pos
data Pos = One | Succ Pos
data Int = Pos Nat | Neg Pos
```

Alternatively you could just stay with `Int = Pos Nat | Neg Nat` but interpret `Neg n` to represent `-(n+1)` instead of `-n`, so “`-0`” won't be possible.

For rationals it's more tricky. I think it's usually the best thing to just leave these non-normalised values implementationally possible but semantically consider only equivalence classes of these values, or normalise them using a smart constructor. That's certainly the approach that [`Rational`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Ratio.html) takes.
It *is* possible to restrict the definition so only a single representative of each equivalenct class exists. This is [how Agda defines the rationals:](https://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Data.Rational.html)

```
record ℚ : Set where
  field
    numerator     : ℤ
    denominator-1 : ℕ
    isCoprime     : True (C.coprime? ∣ numerator ∣ (suc denominator-1))

  denominator : ℤ
  denominator = + suc denominator-1

  coprime : Coprime numerator denominator
  coprime = toWitness isCoprime
```

So, it basically just encodes the gcd ≡ 1 condition in its dependent type system. Lucky those who have such a type system...

I don't know how well such a definition could be translated to Haskell. It should be possible *somehow*, but I doubt it's feasible.

One solution that would definitely work but probably be very inefficient is to [enumerate all rational numbers](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/sandip/acl2-09/presentations/rationals-talk.pdf), and simply store just the index of that enumeration as a single `Nat`. Or rather implement that Calkin-Wilf tree of all positive rationals:

```
data PosRational = UnitRatio
                 | RatSucc PosRational
                 | RecipSucc PosRational
```

The interesting thing would be how to define the `Num` etc. instances for that. Let's see...

```
instance Fractional PosRational where
  recip UnitRatio = UnitRatio
  recip (RecipSucc x) = RatSucc $ recip x
  recip (RatSucc x) = RecipSucc $ recip x

instance Num PosRational where
  UnitRatio + x = RatSucc x
  x + UnitRatio = RatSucc x
  RatSucc x + y = RatSucc $ x + y
  x + RatSucc y = RatSucc $ x + y
  RecipSucc (RecipSucc x) + RecipSucc (RecipSucc y)
   -- = recip (1 + 1 + x) + recip (1 + 1 + y)
   -- = (2+y + 2+x) / ((2+x)*(2+y))
   -- = (4 + x + y) / (4 + 2*x + 2*y + x*y)
   -- = 1 / (1 + (x+y+x*y)/(4+x+y))
      = RecipSucc $ (4+x+y)/(x+y+x*y)
  RecipSucc (RatSucc x) + RecipSucc (RatSucc y)
   -- = recip (1 + recip (1+x)) + recip (1 + recip (1+y))
   -- = (1+x) / (1+x + 1) + (1+y) / (1+y + 1)
   -- = ((1+x)*(2+y)+(1+y)*(2+x)) / ((2+x)*(2+y))
   -- = (2+2*x+y+x*y + 2+x+2*y+x*y) / (4+2*x+2*y+x*y)
   -- = (4 + 3*x + 3*y + 2*x*y) / (4+2*x+2*y+x*y)
   -- = (4+2*x+2*y+x*y + x+y+x*y) / (4+2*x+2*y+x*y)
   -- = 1 + (x+y+x*y) / (4+2*x+2*y+x*y)
   -- = 1 + 1 / (1 + (4+x+y)/(x+y+x*y))
      = RatSucc . RecipSucc $ (4+x+y)/(x+y+x*y)
  ...
```

Comment: Thx a lot, I think this answer is exactly what I want. But I still want to know what is  [quotient types](http://jozefg.bitbucket.org/posts/2014-10-17-quotients.html)  which  @Benjamin Hodgson has mentioned about (in the comment of this problem), and if dependent type can handle all these problems, why we need the quotient types?

Comment: @luochen1990 well, quotient types essentially fix the ambiguity of implementation-different values that are supposed to form an equivalence class _on the language-level_. You can always fake this on the code level, and with dependent types you can in fact kind of _implement_ it in the types.

Answer (score 2):

Mathematically, integers would be defined from natural numbers in the same way rationals are defined from integers: as a pair of natural numbers, but with the *difference* being the defining factor.

```
data MyInt = I Nat Nat
-- I (Succ Zero) Zero is 1
-- I Zero (Succ Zero) is -1
```

---

Now, we have the same problem for both, which is that `I` and `Rational` both can create multiple distinct but *equivalent* values. You could just ignore this and define all your operations to handle it. Here are simple `Eq` instances for each:

```
-- for reference
instance Eq Nat where
  Zero == Zero = True
  (Succ n1) == (Succ n2) = n1 == n2
  _ == _ = False

-- No Num instance for Nat, since you can't negate a Nat
natAdd (Succ n) m = Succ (natAdd n m)
natAdd Zero m = m

instance Eq MyInt where
  (I a b) == (I c d) = a `natAdd` d == b `natAdd` c

-- Assuming an appropriate Num MyInt instance for (*)
instance Eq Rational where
  (Rational n1 d1) == (Rational n2 d2) = n1 * d2 == n2 * d1
```

For other operations, the actual value used to represent an integer doesn't really matter. Here's part of the `Num` instance for `MyInt`, where we work with the relative difference between the pair, not caring about the pair itself.

```
instance Num MyInt where

  negate (I a b) = I b a
  signum (I a b) | a == b = I Zero
                 | a > b = I (Succ Zero) Zero
                 | otherwise = I Zero (Succ Zero)
  abs (I a b) | a >= b = I a b
              | otherwise  = I b a
 (I a b) + (I c d) == I (a `natAdd` c) (b `natAdd` d)
 (I a b) * (I c d) == ... -- you get the idea
```

---

Or, you can avoid the use of the constructor directly and only allow values to be created via smart constructors. This way, only one canonical representation can be created for each integer/rational value.

```
-- Ensure that Zero is always used as a base for
-- defining an integer
mkInt :: Nat -> Nat -> MyInt
mkInt a b | a > b = I (a - b) Zero
          | otherwise = I Zero (b - a)

-- assuming gcd :: MyInt -> MyInt -> MyInt is defined somewhere
mkRat :: MyInt -> MyInt -> Rational
mkRat n d :: Rational (gcd n d) intOne
             where intOne = mkInt (Succ Zero) Zero
```